# Will concerns regarding the move to CC BY-SA 4.0 elicit any further dialogue from Stack Exchange, Inc.?

Tags: support, legal, licensing, creative-commons

Fifteen days ago, it was suddenly announced that [the user-contributed content on Stack Exchange had been relicensed as CC BY SA 4.0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333089/155739).

The change took immediate *and retroactive* effect and is still in place.

However, [serious concerns were immediately raised about the legality and morality of this change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/333094/155739).

To date, there has been no further engagement from Stack Exchange, Inc. on this subject, and consequently there is no indication as to whether these concerns are being considered.

Due to the legal nature of the issue I would understand if Stack Exchange, Inc. has opted to consult their legal partners before making any further statements on the topic.

If that is the case, I respectfully suggest that (at the very least) a short statement to that effect would be in order, as it has already been more than two weeks that the content has been [potentially illegally] re-licensed network-wide. Every day that this is the case, more content is posted, and if indeed the re-licensing of older content is ultimately deemed non-compliant, the technical can of worms involved in remedying the situation grows in mass and squirmishness.

If it is not the case, are there any plans to revisit this topic and feed back to the community as to what the next steps may be to resolve this dispute?

If there are no such plans, please consider that this is not just bikeshedding or whining or complaining or trolling. Licensing of our content, which to a large degree *is* the Stack Exchange Network, is a serious issue and deserves to be treated seriously.

And, if Stack Exchange, Inc. deems the concerns to be without merit, will we hear a confirmation of that so that we can proceed on that basis?

Comment: Thanks for asking this.  I've been checking daily to see if there has been a response and I find it very concerning that only the crickets are making noise.

Comment: @NathanOliver And, let's face it, that's just not cricket.

Comment: Honestly, I'd like to know which specific provisions of the new license people disagree with. Is it the moral rights provision? Is it the 30-day grace period for those who violate the license to correct the violation? Something else?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog There is nothing about CC BY-SA 4.0 that I object to.  What I do object to is that the license I have granted to SE has been changed by SE without any sort of warning or consultation.  I gave permission for them to use CC BY-SA 3.0, not CC BY-SA 4.0.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I was having a hard time understanding why such a license change would provoke *this much* discontent unless people disagreed with a specific provision of the new license.

Comment: A bit of a side observation: SE has spent *heavily* on their goodwill and trust in the last year and change.  This would likely still be a somewhat contentious change, but many more users would overall trust SE and subside with a bit of grumbling.  Now, though...it's unfortunate, but there is a whole lot less goodwill and trust to draw from.  It will take transparency (not only in this aspect) to regain that trust.

Comment: In a [now-deleted comment moved to chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7893343#7893343), CM animuson said: "*Rather than attempting to state things in big bold letters, it makes more sense to rephrase this answer to ask if we consulted lawyers, whether this is allowed, and whether we've considered all the implications.*" The implication appears to be that they *did* already consult their legal team.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I'm not sure I read that in the same way, but thank you for bringing it to us regardless. (It's worth noting that he was then directly asked the question, but did not respond.)

Comment: Being a product support specialist, animuson is almost surely not privy to that information, anyway. The way I read his comment, all available context considered, was that he was just ticked off at the response people were having to an announcement by his company.

Comment: @TylerH: I hate to say it, but as mentioned upthread, SE has spent down its stock of goodwill, and no longer has the right to complain about that. They should go into these announcements *expecting* people to respond negatively, and be pleasantly surprised if that doesn't happen. I don't like it, but that's the way things are right now.

Comment: Somebody might be able to get a lawyer smart enough to sue SE. Then they'll have to provide a response.

Comment: @JL2210, Note that many here might be stymied by the arbitration agreement in place for most users, unless they specifically opted out of it. I have specifically opted out of it. And I'm sure I'm not the only one. I now wonder if that arbitration wasn't perhaps put in place in anticipation of this licensing issue being legally contentious.

Comment: @ouflak By my understanding, as an EU citizen (just about) that whole "mandatory arbitration" thing is non-binding for me anyway. It's an example of a thing you can't just stick in a TOS and say "that's it, we're safe".

Comment: If it is of any use to anybody, I am an EU citizen (for atleast a few more weeks anyway) and an American citizen, and I have specifically opted out of the arbitration. The EU question of applicability could still perhaps be debated. I don't believe my opt-out is debatable. Nor was I ever asked permission to transfer any of my previous content to any new license.

Comment: @Kevin I'm not suggesting whether animuson has a "right" to do what he did (though I think of course he has a right to do what he wants; the employees are not their company), only offering my opinion on *why* he posted as a reason for why the comment shouldn't be given any undue weight in this conversation.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog If Stackexchange can unilaterily relicense BY-SA 3.0 to CC BY-SA 4.0, what is to stop them from relicensing it again to "we own everything"? I'm not sure I feel comfortable contributing to a site that can do that.

Comment: Besides, polling five people on meta is irrelevant. Any person who has contributed in the past may have a disagreement with CC BY-SA 4.0. We just can't know. The whole point of licence agreements is that the terms of use are set in stone from the outset, so that you don't have to go around polling everybody for their opinions many years later: you just read the licence to know what they've agreed to. When a licence agreement is violated, that betrays the whole system, and this is something that a business literally founded on strong software development principles and practices ought to know.

Comment: "Will...?" So far not. (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/333745/260073)

Comment: @Trilarion Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: I really wish those crickets would be quiet!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit everything is loud in an echo chamber

Comment: I have tried to raise awareness to this issue and refuse to participate in this community any longer until changes are made.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-zEUl2UmJo

Comment: [There is now a response](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/333912/155659)

Comment: @OrangeDog Sort of

Comment: Noice, authorative reference notice removed by staff. Lucky me it's archived: https://web.archive.org/web/20190928130246/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333615/will-concerns-regarding-the-move-to-cc-by-sa-4-0-elicit-any-further-dialogue-fro

Comment: @PrincessOlivia I actually don't see it on the archive, though I do remember seeing it in person. Hmm.

Comment: ... what? It was there yesterday. I think. I could've sworn I saw it anyway. Oh well

Comment: @PrincessOlivia The Wayback machine is "coincidentally" missing all captures of this page between the day the bounty was cast, and the day after the CM removed the bounty text. It has one or more captures on every other day.

Comment: They can't have-... whaa... The URL points to a capture on the 28th, but the archive redirected to one on the 29th. That means they somehow intentionally got it removed.

Comment: @PrincessOlivia Good spot! Oh, my. That's rather frightening.

Comment: @PrincessOlivia Do you recall what the content of the authoritative notice was?  Separately, I checked the Lumen Database and couldn't find any DMCA requests that appeared pertinent.  I'm as curious as you are what procedure SE used to request the removal from archive.org!

Comment: @cxw I don't remember the exact wording unfortunately, but it was roughly: "This needs a reply from SE. Ignoring it further won't help your already low trust". Needs a mod to recover everything - assuming they're able to. It criticized their decision to ignore issues instead of handling the problems head on. Again, the exact wording might be off, and I'm pretty sure it was a little longer

Comment: @PrincessOlivia Thanks for the quick response!  I have saved a PDF copy of this page on my local PC :) .

Comment: I remember thinking that it wasn't the deliberately cautious language I was trying to use in the question itself, but that beyond that it wasn't in any way rude or offensive or certainly worthy of not just deletion but full erasure from the history of the entire internet. The lengths this company is going to, to stifle dissent, right now, _is_ offensive, particularly at a time when you'd think they'd be doing the opposite.

Comment: It goes with the news that SE engineers were [_manually removing stars from dissenting opinions_ in moderator chat](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4576/12378). I mean that's just ridiculous. Seriously, come on guys. It gains you nothing and loses you everything, as we're now seeing. Add on [freezing of the meta room so that nobody can talk any more](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389935/560648). You're literally waging a war against the very people who create the content you're trying to make money off. Duh.

Comment: They did *not* retroactively change the license. This phrasing is incorrect. They are *in violation* of the old license granted to them by all licensers (the individual community members) ever since they started misrepresenting that they changed to CC BY-SA 4.0.

Comment: @Prof.Falken Okay, fair: mentally add "intended to" or "purport to" before that phrase. However, see comments above: I deliberately kept the question's wording as neutral as possible, avoiding an outright assertion on the legality (or otherwise) of the action. I suppose, in that sense, I failed, since as you've pointed out I've accidentally made it sound like I'm saying it was legal. Anyway, I think we can leave it as it is since all parties are pretty much familiar with the situation by now.

Comment: @PrincessOlivia It's somehow back on [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20190926010217/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333615/will-concerns-regarding-the-move-to-cc-by-sa-4-0-elicit-any-further-dialogue-fro) again (and downloaded as html...). The notice was "Will you please just reply already? We ***need*** answers. This being ignored will not improve relations between users and the company, nor will it increase your already low trust."

Comment: @ba weird. At least it's back. Maybe there was a server issue that hid it? With no apparent takedown request, that seems like the most likely reason. idk, this is still weird. At least we got the notice back

Comment: @Princess Observe how it only resurfaced after we discovered, then publicly reported, that it had been hidden.

Comment: @PrincessOlivia Looks to me like it's gone again - I see nothing after 4am on the 26th September (same goes for [the MSE homepage](https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://meta.stackexchange.com) though - maybe there's something else going on)

Comment: @PrincessOlivia the archive works and has the bounty message, currently.

Comment: **SE added a feedback survey**: [Info](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/25/introducing-the-loop-a-foundation-in-listening/), [**Survey**](https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/Z2YDMRD). This is your chance to give them your feedback.

Comment: @mbomb007 Thanks, but they've had it for some time.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

**One week later...**

Okay, well, I guess we have our answer.

To say that I am disappointed in this company's behaviour would be a gross understatement.

I tried to politely offer the option of direct discourse, and you ignored me.

Shame on you. We'll see where this takes us next.

Comment: Wow! I did not wait this extraordinary attitude from you. :-) Btw, are you sure that this is the problem? I don't think that an unexpected change from "CC BY SA 3.0" to "CC BY SA 4.0" would be a serious violation. Although the SE probably can't do that.

Comment: @peterh That they "probably can't do that" and have so far decided not to speak a single word on the topic is exactly the problem. If my attitude seems extraordinary, that's because the situation is extraordinary.

Comment: It's entirely possible that there is a long internal discussion taking place as to how to respond to this. But, as Monica Cellio once famously said on Medium, internal discussions mean nothing for the public record.

Comment: They actually don't have the right to change existing content licenses of content we own. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/333094/285610

Comment: [Tim added a follow up answer on his post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/333912/291223).  It doesn't actually answer anything about the legalities so my conclusion is they aren't and won't unless legal action is taken.  Maybe I'll just find a different site.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Good morning! :-O

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for the link. And yeah.

Comment: So what should be the course of action now for concerned users? An immediate class lawsuit would be impractical and expensive for everyone involved, but we could, for instance, announce a 24-hours 'strike' in which we abstain from all contributions to SE. If sufficiently advertised on the meta sites (with enough advance) it could gain some traction.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni [we have bigger problems than licensing atm](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/332043). If it continues, the moderator force will be significantly reduced, and risks becoming non-existent on small sites.

Comment: @PrincessOlivia Oh, my.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, [that's not going to happen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper/333975#comment1090891_333992).  (For context in case the linked comment is deleted—someone already attempted to create such a Meta post, calling for a strike, and Tim Post deleted it and said it would have to be done on a separate website or blog.  Which frankly makes sense to me.)

Comment: "We'll see where this takes us next." I fear it takes us into the realm of prolonged legal uncertainty. I think that a lawsuit is actually the only reasonable, but unfortunately expensive action left to clarify the matter (short of giving up).

Comment: @Trilarion I'm still hoping the EFF can help us.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The EFF is not interested in taking up the case. They have forwarded my concerns on to their listing.

Comment: @jhpratt That's unfortunate :( I thought this was literally what they were for.

Comment: If legal action is possible, and someone were interested in taking that route, what would be the correct way to do so?

Comment: More than a month. Still no [meaningful] engagement.

Comment: @jhpratt I can't think of anything more relevant to at least one of the organizations to whom you made enquiries. I thought that's bread and butter work for EFF and FSF! I can try nagging Berkman at Harvard and Stanford's Center for Internet and Society (or whatever they call it) on Twitter. Tomorrow we will breach the [30-day license misuse cure period for CC 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/Version4/), with more details [here](https://creativecommons.org/faq/#what-happens-if-i-offer-my-material-under-a-creative-commons-license-and-someone-misuses-them).

Comment: @EllieKesselman Feel free to reach out! My contact info can be found on GitHub (username is the same).

Comment: @jhpratt Hi! I will hunt you down on Github. (I'm there too.)

Comment: @EllieKesselman Any updates? Unless it went to spam, I never received anything from you.

Comment: @jhpratt I followed you on Github, but no updates to report. Other things took precedence and I feel sad about SO.

Answer (score 37):

Yes, it will.

As Teresa wrote in her [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343890/the-company-s-commitment-to-rebuilding-the-relationship-with-you-our-community):

> We have drafted our followup and clarification on the Content Licensing issue and will be publishing that within the next two weeks.

Our response has been published: [An Update on Creative Commons Licensing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344491/an-update-on-creative-commons-licensing)

Thanks for your patience on this issue.

Comment: The question is more than five months old. Could you maybe comment on what was limiting the ability to draft and post a clarification on the issue in the last months that was received so badly back then?

Comment: @Trilarion Hopefully, that will be included in the followup post itself. If hints were included here, we'd just get a long thread of comments trying to double-guess the full content. If I turn out to be wrong, your question will be a valid response to the new post, but I think it's reasonable for this answer to stick to the bare minimum until the full explanation is ready.

Comment: @Trilarion, I don't believe we will get a clarification on the delay, because it took a change of management to see that an answer was due.