# Has SO apologized for their licensing fait accompli?

Tags: support, status-completed, community, licensing, ceo

In the latest [news from SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/393552/an-account-of-my-meeting-with-the-stack-overflow-management-team), the following was posted (emphasis mine):

> ### Licensing
>
> - MIT licensing of code was proposed, but held back due to community naysayers.
> - CC-BY-SA incremented from 3.0 to 4.0. - likely in good faith.
> - Vast majority of community likely fine with 4.0.
> - Vast majority not fine with *fait accompli*.
> - Some (a very few?) thought that this happened in bad faith.
>
> Stack Overflow:
>
> > - **We have apologized for the *fait accompli*.**
> > - We want to signal our intent to keep up with future changes to CC-BY-SA.
> > - We will create a process and be engaged on licensing issues on Meta.
> > - We have had hours of meetings on this, and it is a big priority.
> > - We have no intention of moving away from creative commons or paywalling users content in any way.

Has that actually happened? Was there any place were SO made any sort of apology related to their actions in the licensing space? The original re-licensing announcement is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333089/stack-exchange-and-stack-overflow-have-moved-to-cc-by-sa-4-0), and there was a follow up post to it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/333912/224667), but I don't see any apologies there, and I don't know of any other posts related to this.

For those suggesting that [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333615/will-concerns-regarding-the-move-to-cc-by-sa-4-0-elicit-any-further-dialogue-fro) question is a dupe of mine, I disagree. It was answered in one week and its possible SO did something since then. The SO leadership seems to have explicitly stated something was made, which is in direct contrast with the answer in that post.

Comment: Of all apologies I've seen on SE the answer from Tim is at least not a hollow one. It explains why they have done that and that they will stick with it. Not all apologies need *sorry* in it. Better not.

Comment: @rene I think we have a difference of definitions here. I absolutely think that _all_ apologies need a sorry (or something similar) in them. I see nothing like that from Tim. I agree Tim's post did a good job of explaining in more depth the why of their decision. It did not though attempt to make an apology, and I don't understand how one could qualify his post as one.

Comment: We certainly have differences. Glad we do.

Comment: @rene Don't mean to nitpick, and maybe we should move to chat, but I'm now really curious. How do you define an apology? What is it about Tim's post that makes it an apology?

Comment: Not everything needs an apology.

Comment: @user400654 But if you *specifically say* that you apologised for something, you should have in fact actually apologised for it.

Comment: so, your problem is that maybe they lied? maybe misinformed? i mean... ? so what. if that's the biggest problem we have, it's smooth sailing from here on

Comment: @user400654 I agree not everyhing needs an apology, but it is claimed that the _CEO_ (or possibly Ben Popper/Sara Chipps) said that there was an apology. I'm not asking them to make one now. I'm asking for evidence of a statement that has been claimed to exist

Comment: @user56reinstatemonica8 what more would they do than say “we apologize for this?” I don’t get what this question wants.

Comment: @Stormblessed I think the point is, don't say "We have apologized for the fait accompli" if you a) haven't apologised and b) as a policy, intend to continue with "fait acompli" i.e. changes without prior consultation. Do one or the other: either apologise and commit to consult next time, or, don't apologise and stand by not consulting (ideally, with a reason *why* they won't consult). To not apologise then pretend they did is just confusing, and means no-one knows where they stand (except... we *do* know where we really stand, and that's the problem - which they deny).

Comment: @Stormblessed the question is pretty straight forward. SE claims that they apologized for something, and this is asking if that's true, as simple as that

Comment: @rene I think you are talking about justifying something, not apologizing

Comment: The word "sorry" is not needed, but some elements are usually required: https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Apology#Which_elements_should_be_included_in_an_apology

Comment: "fair accompli"? I'm more concerned by the fact that the relicensing was **illegal** than the fact that they didn't tell us beforehand. Though if they told us, then we might have at least been able to point this out (even I bet they would have gone ahead and done it anyway)

Comment: Before an apology, they would need to actually ask the user to re-license their content. I was not asked up to now, so they still do not have a valid CC4 license for my old content.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We have [posted an update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344491/an-update-on-creative-commons-licensing) on the Licensing issue. Please see there for a recap of what happened, what we are going to be doing in the short term, as well as what issues still remain open.

Additionally, to quote Tim Post in [a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344491/an-update-on-creative-commons-licensing#comment1154174_344494) on his post:

> …I honestly feel the hurt, and I'm sorry for it. I'm just glad you're still here to say it, and thanks for staying

Comment: Sorry but I have to downvote and disagree with marking this as completed, since the update contains no apology. The word "sorry" does not exist in there, and neither the word "mistake". It's just, well... an update. (Blessed one, sure, but that's not the question here.)

Comment: @ShadowWizardisEarForYou I am also sorry that you feel that you have to downvote. I have added Tim's comment from the other post. I am sorry, but the words that you are looking for will probably not be added to the other statement. However, this update is our official response and plan for this issue (hence marking this question completed).

Comment: *Sigh*... if I would vote by heart/feeling I'd give +1000 here. Wait, I can. *looking for start bounty button*

Answer (score 41):

To be blunt: No.

It's been presented as a done deal, and no one has addressed it since the "our lawyers told us we're in the clear, try and sue us" post.

An apology would be an admission that they did something wrong, and probably would involve some kind of liability. Don't expect one. That's just the way things are now.

Comment: IANAL but you might read https://scholarship.law.missouri.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1313&context=jdr before making assertions about the relationship between apologizing and liability.