# Has anyone sued SE for changing licensing?

Tags: discussion, legal, licensing, creative-commons

There seems to be a lot of current drama flowing from the post [Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow are moving to CC BY-SA 4.0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333089/217279) and related activities.

It seems like some authors who published under 3.0 are upset about the change to 4.0 (*oversimplifying*). It would seem to me that each of those authors has a legal case, against SE.

Have there been an formal legal proceedings started?

Comment: We simply can't talk about litigation, even the absence thereof, or provide a forum for it.

Comment: Hello @TimPost, thank you for your quick response. I wanna clarify the use of the word _forum_ here. If the effects of such litigation, or its absence, threatens or affects the future of the site, then certainly this would be a pertinent discussion to have.

Comment: @Rath, this has nothing to do with that. And, it's not a discussion we're going to host.