# Is there a policy on "important things on MSO copied to MSE" posts?

Tags: discussion, meta

Last month, the new Stack Exchange CEO made a post on MSO to engage with the community: [CEO's 2020 Kickoff Blog: Where do you see Stack Overflow going?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/393155) Since this was important for the entire network community but not everyone visits (or even has an account on) MSO, it was cross-posted here to get feedback from the whole network community as well as just the MSO community: ["Scripting the Future of Stack Overflow" blog post discussion on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342650/278659)

This month, Aaron Hall made a post on MSO to recount the tale of his meeting with the new CEO and what was said: [An account of my meeting with the Stack Overflow management team](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/393552) Again, this is important for the entire network community, but it took until today for someone to cross-post this one here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344082/278659 Surprisingly (to me), the latter post was heavily downvoted and closed, then deleted by some MSE regulars.

**Why such a different reaction to these two cross-postings from MSO to MSE?** Was it because today's post is a complete copy-paste instead of just a short "go and look at this thing on MSO"? Or because it's not posted by a CM/employee? Or because it's so much later than the original post rather than on the same day? Despite all that, though, it still seems *useful* to show the stuff to the network community as well as just the MSO community.

Is there (or should there be) a policy on copying important MSO things to MSE?

Comment: In case it matters, [the reason given](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344082/an-account-of-aaron-halls-meeting-with-the-stack-overflow-management-team#comment1152731_344082) for cross-posting to MSE was, "Because without an MSO account have no way of interacting with the post, and even as very active user I did not see this on the featured list. Plus, once it is off's the featured list it is not visible at all outside MSO.".

Comment: It's arguable that if it wasn't posted here, then it's not important ;)

Comment: Is there an argument for setting up migrations from other Metas to MSE?

Comment: @Kramii The main problem is not just setting up a migration path but convincing people to use it. Who's going to tell the CEO "you posted on the wrong site" and move his question to a different one?

Comment: My "policy" is to close and delete any attempt to post official announcement by someone who is not authorized for this. If SE want to cross post, SE staff should do it, not ordinary user. That's the reason for my downvote and delete vote. (Was already closed when I first saw it.)

Comment: @Shadow ... uh, what? If you didn't notice, the original announcement wasn't by an SE staff member either. Nor was the cross-poster pretending to be any sort of official representative, either of SE or of Mr Hall.

Comment: @Randal'Thor well, the original announcement was very close, by a mod who met personally with the CEO. So in that specific case, it was his role to cross-post. Never said the author of the post here pretended to be official, just that I personally don't think it's fitting, and hence my deletion.

Answer (score 5):

Official policy - not as far as I'm aware.

That said I and others have in the past have brought up items of interest elsewhere on the network, and some things just work better than others.

An impactful meta post of the sort isn't and shouldn't be a mirror. We can have it much simpler than that

We need to introduce the topic in summary, bring in the key things that would interest the MSE public and have a call to action for answers.

It also needs to be timely (there's new developments since and it's hardly a hot topic). That the post was a little older may not have helped.

We can trust people to read a post elsewhere. We just need them to know why and open the floor for feedback amd responses.

In addition to the example Rand gave consider my [post here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332499/how-could-we-improve-our-planned-post-notice-improvements).

It's 3 paragraphs. I introduce the post. I go into why it is of interest to meta. I give a precis of content of interest and well, it worked better than a full mirror. You will find Juan's post is similar.

Answer (score 2):

No matter who posts it, I think no question should be cross-posted as a copy/paste between two graduated sites or between the Meta sites of two graduated sites.

I think the question that you are referring to should have been posted to MSE rather than MSO because it is relevant to more than just the Stack Overflow site.  However, unless it is deleted from MSO, which I am not advocating, then it should not be cross-posted here.

There is no problem linking to it, and even quoting parts from it, in new questions here for which those parts provide context.

Comment: In other words, the important difference between the old cross-post and the new one is just that the new one *copies the full text* of the MSO post rather than just linking to it? That could easily be fixed by an edit to the new question.

Comment: I don’t think it could be “easily” fixed with an edit because a “99% cross-post” is still a cross-post. I think a major edit is needed to extract just a paragraph or two at a time to get its content over here, if that is important, into new and more focused questions.

Comment: I meant a quick edit to make it more like JuanM's post in January: rather than copy-pasting, just saying "this thing is on MSO, the wider community should see it too". But you're right, providing a short summary of the MSO post would be better.

Comment: I think there should be substantially more of a value add than the example you just gave and I think we should be asking new questions about parts of it to add value in preference to merely summarizing it.

Comment: "No matter who posts it" - wrong, at least for me. SE has the right to cross post, but only someone from inside the company.