# SEDE footer still links to version 3.0 of Creative Commons license

Tags: discussion, status-completed, data-explorer, licensing, creative-commons

According to [Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow have moved to CC BY-SA 4.0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333089/295232), subscriber content is now licensed under version 4.0 of the Creative Commons license. The change is reflected in the [footer](/#footer) of each Q&A site:

> user contributions licensed under [cc by-sa 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).

The footer has been adjusted on other sites as well, e.g. the [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/). However, the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/#footer) still has the old footer referring to version 3.0 of the license:

> user contributions licensed under [cc by-sa 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) with [attribution required](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/attribution-required/)

Is this an oversight or was this intended? Also, [Area 51's footer](https://area51.stackexchange.com/#footer) already links to 4.0, but it's named 'cc-wiki' instead, which is a bit confusing.

Comment: Simple: nobody has pushed the required change, or someone did and SE staff didn't approve the change yet. SEDE is a weird beast: it's open source, not part of SE codebase, and using SE actual database, not API. So such things are totally expected, and SEDE is behind in great many aspects because there's nobody who can make the required code changes there. :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I went ahead an created a new pull request #93

[Updated the license to cc-by-sa 4.0 if warranted](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/93)

that is now pending a merge to master from Nick Craver and subsequent deployment.

Maybe this PR can be handled with the other PR's. I'm lacking a Twitter account but if Twitter driven development is a thing then maybe someone can nudge Nick.

Comment: Taryn merged the pull request to master and it went live.