# SEDE help page still links to version 3.0 of Creative Commons license

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer, licensing, creative-commons

Related to the post : [SEDE footer still links to version 3.0 of Creative Commons license](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338959/312043).

In the Stack Exchange Data Explorer [help page](https://data.stackexchange.com/help), currently the Creative Commons license is referred with version 3.0.

> The data available here is similar to the data you can find in the Stack Exchange data dumps that are hosted on the Internet Archive and licensed under CC BY-SA 3.0. Developers looking ....

Can the help page also be referred with version 4.0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is done. I just merged the PR and pushed a build.

Comment: Thanks for the merge :)

Comment: This was a wrong PR because the old content published before 2019-09-05 is still 3.0-licensed. You're not allowed to change the license without explicit permissions from the contributors.

Answer (score 3):

I made a change for the creative commons version update to refer version 4.0 in the [/help page](https://data.stackexchange.com/help), and raised the pull request #95.

[Updated the license to cc-by-sa 4.0 in /help page](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/95).