# Could someone legally replace Stack Exchange in posting the data dumps to the Internet Archive?

Tags: discussion, data-dump

Recently the user discovered that without any official communication [the company stopped posting the monthly data dump to the Internet Archive web site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389922/june-2023-data-dump-is-missing). Causes are currently unknown but some users theorize this is tied to [an ongoing attempt to monetize users contributions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388551/is-se-going-to-be-selling-our-content-for-ai-model-training-and-what-exactly?noredirect=1&lq=1).

This got me wondering: since all content on the site is available under the CC BY-SA license 4.0, could some users technically join up to provide the same service the company is no longer giving? And what would be the legal options to do so? In a way this is tangential to the existence of all the "mirror" unofficial sites that have been reproducing content available on Stack Exchange (sometime without proper attribution) for years.

---

Note: this is just a theoretical post for exploring options. I am not actually advocating any action as now.

Comment: Perhaps people from https://law.stackexchange.com/ can guide us in some way.

Comment: @RandomPerson could be an idea.

Comment: Feel free to post this question on Law SE too.

Comment: Even if we legally can (I'm not a lawyer, though), they can shut down the method used, such as the (free) API. It would break a _lot_ of community projects, but they could

Comment: @RandomPerson no need, the answer is clearly 100% yes, someone can legally replace Stack Exchange in posting the data dumps to the Internet Archive.

Comment: Question would be practically - where would you get a source of 'updated' data?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek that I have no idea. Somehow those "clone" sites manage to do it, and I doubt they use the dump. Probably some web crawler thing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The CC-BY-SA license tells you what you can do with the content. It does not address use of the company's servers. When we author content here and give SE a license to use it, but nothing compels SE to distribute it to everyone who is permitted by the license to use the content.

If someone has their own copy of all the posts here, they're free to use them under the terms of the license, including distributing them (per the terms of the license). However, if they'd like to use the copy someone else has, obtaining that copy is subject to any limits that other party wants to put on that transfer. Clearly some transfers, like a user browsing through questions and answers, are necessary for general use of the site, so the company is always going to permit those uses if they want the site to exist. That process gives you a copy of the content, and then you're free to use it as the license permits.

Querying their servers to obtain *all* the content, though, is not something the license forces them to do. That would really be quite a pressure on users of the licensed content, if they were required to provide anyone a copy of every example of such content they had at any time.

Comment: I was thinking more of other available options like the sede explorer and such, just exploring ideas.

Comment: @SPArcheon The company is not required to give you access to SEDE, though, and if they do give you access to SEDE, they can certainly impose terms and limits on its use (they already do).

Comment: yep. like I said this is just exploring the concept.

Comment: There were promises made to users about data dumps being available that might be enforceable.

Comment: It's very unlikely that any such promises would be enforceable. A contract is only valid if it has consideration for both parties; "we promise to do X" doesn't create a contract, whereas "we promise to do X if you do Y" might create a contract. Even then it's doubtful, because forming a contract requires a "meeting of the minds", i.e. both parties have to consent to the terms of the contract; merely announcing "we promise to do X if you do Y" followed by us doing Y doesn't necessarily mean we agreed to those terms. And, who is the counterparty? SE users aren't represented by one entity.

Answer (score 15):

Legally, yes. CC-by-SA doesn't stipulate where the data comes from, just that the attribution clauses all line up and that any modifications of the content are redistributed with the same license.

Technologically, there are significant hurdles that all but prohibit this from a feasible perspective. Getting that much data from the site may result in you being rate limited, and you don't have convenient access to everything the dumps provided, like post history or user badge info.

Comment: well, there is SEDE, which from my understanding is the data dumps with a bit less info. With enough patience, couldn't you just pull everything you can out of there and republish it / rehost it?

Comment: @starball the Data Dump is *literally* dumped from the SEDE databases.