# What initiatives exist to create a publicly available dump of SE under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license?

Tags: discussion, data-dump

SE is [not providing a dump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390040/178179) for the time being. They may do it again in the future, but with some restrictive ToS/license/etc.

This makes me wonder: What initiatives exist to create a publicly available dump of SE under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license? I am asking as [anyone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390034/178179) can scrape SE and upload the data somewhere under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license.

Comment: You didn't get an answer on your previous question (you waited 10 minutes), and seem to build upon an assumed answer already with this question. Maybe give it a second?

Comment: @MissSkooter I wrote "They may do it again in the future, but with some restrictive ToS/license/etc." I'm not making any assumption

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt with respect, Miss Skooter is right. While I appreciate your enthusiasm on the topic, I believe this is effectively a duplicate in the current context. Please take a look at my (longest ever?) answer on your other question, and consider whether you really need to ask this separately.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can SE gate access to the Dump that will allow individuals access to the data while preventing "misuse" by for-profit organizations?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390043/how-can-se-gate-access-to-the-dump-that-will-allow-individuals-access-to-the-dat)

Comment: @BryKKan Thanks, no it's a different question, why do you think it's a dupe? Regardless of whether SE can gate, they can still simply decide not to release anything.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt it isn't literally duplicate. IMHO it's premature to ask this literally though. The spirit of this is trying to "solve the problem" of the missing data dumps. But your other question invites a more comprehensive answer to that which overlaps practically with this Q. I naturally already covered the "meat and potatoes" of your concerns over there. For instance, one of the first things I addressed was the possibility they could turn off the tap entirely. I also hit on how we could expect people to react generally, and gave an example of how we might do just what you suggested.