What will be the actual impact of SE's "socially responsible AI" policy?
When the company announced the partnerships with Google and OpenAI they made a big deal out of their commitment to "socially responsible AI" (see this blog post for details). A big part of this seems to be the attribution requirements of the Creative Commons license.
Now, the OpenAI agreement is just days old and the Google agreement was a few months ago, so I don't necessarily expect some immediate impact here. But as far as I can tell Google Gemini isn't citing any sources yet.
I have a bit of trouble believing that SE has the power to get huge companies with many billions on the line to fundamentally change the way their hottest product right now would work. There's also some technical arguments here that LLMs fundamentally cannot provide attribution. I don't feel entirely competent to judge those arguments, and the way AI tools work might change in the future so while I wouldn't rule out that attribution is possible, I think it is at least very, very hard and probably impossible for at least some use cases.
So what actual, tangible effects will the "socially responsible AI" policy have on AI tools of the cooperation partners? What does SE here expect, and does this policy actually mean that ChatGPT and Google Gemini are expected to attribute content from SE sites in the reasonably near future?

I expect a lot of people want the answer to this question more than most other questions, but it depends how they implement it and what constraints are imposed on them by their contract-partners (and if they pay attention to the community's wishes). They've not told us about that yet.

A related answer from a while back: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/388569/273494 genAI is perfectly capable of providing plausible looking citations. That doesn't mean they are relevant. If you look at the citations in Jon's answer, they have multiple problems. The underlying problem is that we have no way of knowing if the citation/attribution is correct because we have no visibility into how it was determined to be relevant.

Gemini is and has been citing sources.
Here is an example of Gemini citing sources, specifically a Stack Overflow question:

Here is an example of Google's AI Search / SGE citing sources, specifically a Software Engineering Stack Exchange question:

It's important to distinguish between "citation" and "attribution".
Per the CC license, attribution is required when resharing or adapting (remixing, transforming, etc.) the material. The terms of the license specify the content of the attribution.
Under CC BY-SA 4.0, attribution must include an identification of the authors of the material, a copyright notice, a notice that refers to the license, a notice that refers to the disclaimer of warranties, a URI or hyperlink to the content, an indication of modifications, and a URI or hyperlink to the license. In addition, as permitted by the license, Stack Overflow asks that the attribution include an indication that the content is from the Stack Exchange network, that a hyperlink is used to point to the original question, and that creator names are included and hyperlinked backed to their profile(s), but these are non-binding requests as far as the license is concerned.
Citations allow for ideas to be traced to their sources for the purpose of honesty and ethical behavior. Since I do not believe that Gemini's output can be considered resharing or adapting, I consider citation appropriate here, and Gemini appears to be creating an acceptable citation for the material. In a formal paper, someone may want to use a formal citation format, but that isn't necessarily a requirement to cite sources.
There are numerous citation formats. During my primary education, I was taught to use the MLA format. During my professional work, I typically use the IEEE style or the ISO 690 style. The format for citation is typically driven by the type of work. The necessary information needed varies based on the format, but common elements include the name of authors, editors, and other contributors, a title, the website title, a URL, the date of publication, and the date of access. In informal writing, the citation could very well be much lighter than this, perhaps as light as a URL hyperlink to the original content, perhaps with an identification of an author.
The bar for citing a source is far, far lower than the bar for complying with the CC BY-SA 4.0 attribution requirement.
But let's set citations aside and assume that attribution is required. If this is the case, we can ask if what is provided meets the requirements of the Creative Commons license, and as much as I personally don't like it, I believe it does. According to another section of the CC BY-SA 4.0 license, attribution may be provided in "any reasonable manner based on the medium, means, and context" in which the sharing takes place. It even gives the example that "it may be reasonable to satisfy the conditions by providing a URI or hyperlink to a resource that includes the required information". By giving a hyperlink to a Stack Exchange question that contains supporting information and the SE question page containing all of the elements of attribution, the CC requirements appear to be satisfied.
Currently, it doesn't look like OpenAI's ChatGPT, at least the freely available one, has similar functionality. However, if SE concurs that what Google is doing with Gemini and SGE meets the requirements of the CC license, I would expect that similar functionality implemented by OpenAI would also be seen as meeting the requirement.
There is also a question about attribution regarding training material. In the United States, there are ongoing court cases and pending legislation that may put requirements on identifying material used for training models and limiting what licenses for content can be used to train models. It may take many months, or even years, for these concerns to work their way through the courts and legislatures for final decisions.
I don't think that SE's actions will significantly impact the work of any partners. Court cases and legislation, both in the US and around the world, will have a greater impact. Unless SE starts to advocate for changes to global intellectual property laws and the CC licenses, it seems like the current status quo is acceptable to them.

Interesting, I haven't used Gemini before and it didn't create something like that for me in a few tests. It doesn't look entirely like attribution to me, more like a combination of search and genAI results. But in general the question how to attribute seems almost impossible to me, many genAI answers will not be clearly based on a single source and I don't see how attribution could work there.

@MadScientist In Gemini, you need to click a button for it to highlight content. It will either cite its sources or say no supporting sources can be found. I'd agree that it's not attribution, but I also don't think how CC defines attribution is appropriate, either, since it gives so many outs. But based on how LLMs work, I don't think you can get better than this. The best you can do is trace statements to similar training material. It would be better to link to the Top N supporting sources instead of just one, but it's still a guess since all of the training material impacts the next output.

unless the relevant parts have been cut-off from your picture, in my opinion that is NOT an example of "Gemini providing attribution". Gemini did two things: first, it used Google Search to provide a link to a only tangentially related SO question (notice that it clearly stated "Google search found", NOT "the following Gemini answer was based on"). Second, it used Gemini LLM to create a statistical word chain based on the question. And if you notice, the content it generated is not found in the SO question it linked as similar in the first place.

@SPArcheon You are confusing "citation" and "attribution". Citation is an ethical concern to trace a potential source of an idea. Attribution is a legal concern regarding identifying content used, adapted, remixed, transformed, etc. The examples clearly show Gemini citing sources. I don't see any content sufficiently identical to warrant attribution, so citation is the proper thing to do here. However, even if the content was used in a manner that required attribution, what Google is doing does meet the requirements of the CC Attribution clauses.

@ThomasOwens I fear that you have missed part of the point there. See for example here, here, here or here.

@SPArcheon Which point did I miss? I've also elaborated in my answer on citation vs attribution.

that even if you want to differentiate between citation and attribution (I don't think it really matters on this topic, but you are correct in stating them being sightly different concepts) what Gemini did there by linking an unrelated question that doesn't anywhere express the concept found in the LLM generated answer is neither Citation nor Attribution. To be clear, Gemini answer does not look like it was based on the "cited" content.

@SPArcheon You're referring to the technical correctness of the citation. I looked at both examples again, and I don't see issues. The Gemini example that cites the SO question does have an answer that claims that one return comes from structured programming. The SGE example points to a Software Engineering question that has several answers that refer to readability, understandability, and control flow. I don't agree that the generated content doesn't include concepts expressed in the linked sources.

That AI is making up a somewhat plausible citation is actually worse than none at all. I am highly skeptical that the search results it provided have anything to do with how the algorithm arrived at its answer. Some of them look like AI generated SEO content, but since you only provided a screenshot  I can barely read, it's difficult to tell.

@ThomasOwens I'll agree to disagree. If I answer with some quotes from Gandalf, imho linking a page that  links to another page about Gandalf is not "citing" your sources. In the same way if I am talking about the Agile Manifesto I will cite the official page, not an SO question that has a link to the Manifesto page. But you are free to think the opposite.

@SPArcheon I was always taught to cite what you read. If you read the Agile Manifesto, you cite the Agile Manifesto. If you read my answer on SE or PM that summarizes and interprets the Agile Manifesto and didn't read the original content, then you cite my answer. And if you read both, then you cite both. Of course, this gets fuzzy when you talk about a system that is capable of "reading" and "remembering" everything, what do you need to cite? I've read lots of things that I'm sure influenced my thinking, but I can't cite every single book or post I've ever read on a given topic.

@ColleenV I did check the citations. The linked pages had content that supported the generated content. I didn't analyze to see if the citations themselves were AI generated or not. But in this small sample, there is no evidence of making up citations. This doesn't say anything about other content containing similar information that could also be cited or anything about the correctness of the sources cited. However, the citation is there and the cited sources support the generation. You can always try Gemini or SGE for yourself and see.

I can search Google and give you "citations" that are relevant. That doesn't make them accurate and doesn't help find where the idea came from. It's just a chain of hearsay about where the idea came from that misleads people into believing they know a fact by the way it's presented. This is how we get crazy folk etymologies about the origin of idioms. It is the opposite of socially responsible.

@ColleenV I don't understand that argument. These citations are relevant and correct. Does that mean that they are the original source? No, but that's not the point of a citation. Citations are meant to be a chain. I could write something citing you and ideally you've cited what you read and they cite what they read and it leads back to an original source. Citing the sources used is socially responsible and the ethical thing to do.

You assume because they're relevant and confirm what you believe to be true about where that idea came from that they're correct. Why would you even need a citation in that case? Where did the person that wrote the SE post get the idea? These aren't citations. They're search results.

This is an example of what citation looks like https://quoteinvestigator.com/2024/05/08/new-idea/

@ColleenV I believe you have a fundamental misunderstanding of citations. Citations are not about correctness. They are only about tracing the history of an idea so that one can understand where it comes from to evaluate its correctness on their own. It would be up to the person who wrote the SE post to cite their sources (if any - something could be based solely on experience and not based on someone else's ideas), and we have a policy on citations. You can use the citations (or lack thereof) to decide if you trust a source.

@ColleenV That is not what a citation needs to look like. Is that a good example? Sure. But there are plenty of formal and informal ways to cite someone else's work.

How do search results match that definition of citation? None of those things cited are the origin of the concept. The AI is not citing its sources. It's giving you search results. It's not even putting them in context. It's lying because it doesn't know how it arrived at the information it provided. It just knows the information was somewhere on the internet when it scraped information for its model.

@ColleenV It's not about the origin. It's about what was consumed to make the content. That may or may not be the origin of the concept or idea. Again, this is a fundamental misunderstanding of what a citation is and what purpose it serves. You may have concerns about how the citation is presented, and those may be valid. However, a citation is there and that citation also meets the requirements for attribution under CC BY-SA 4.0.

How do you know it's not lying? You believe because an SE post was returned that it's properly attributed. What if it's not and that post had nothing to do with the information it generated? There's no way to prove that citation is accurate. That it's relevant is not proof. We don't know what data is in the model or how it's tagged.

A proper citation of data in an AI model would include the some sort of date or model version, not just a link to a page that was purportedly scraped to make the model.

@ColleenV Again, accuracy of the cited source is irrelevant. Citations are only about pointing to the source(s) used to trace ideas. The training of the model and creation of the output are also two different concepts entirely. I do agree that there is insufficient information about the training of the model, but the cited content doesn't actually need to be part of the training in order to summarize. Gemini, for example, can summarize a file in Google Drive, including one that I just wrote and filled with novel content. Citing and/or attributing training material is a separate discussion.

My father wrote his PhD years ago. For every note he took from the literature he wrote up a card that told where it came from. That is a "citation". Taking some text and re-running your stochastic search on your corpus with a prompt to "produce something that looks like a citation" is not a citation. This answer is fundamentally wrong.

@JonathanZ The rigor behind citations in a PhD thesis is very different than the rigor behind citations in an SE post (on most sites) or a blog post or a summary of search results. When publishing a thesis or in an academic journal, you would likely be expected to validate your citations and structure them according to strict formatting rules. You cannot compare how you cite sources in a PhD thesis or other academic journal to citing sources used to summarize search results.

Google's search results tags every result with the link it was found at. (Or at least it did for the first twenty years.) That again is a citation. You cannot compare rerunning your stochastic next-word selector to produce something that looks like a citation with an algorithm that actually tracks where it got something from. There is no rule that would prevent someone from creating a LLM that tracked this, but current ones most definitely do not, it's hard to see how to tweak them to do so, and we should not describe what they produce as "citations" until they do.

@JonathanZ Except Google's SGE actually has functionality that tracks what content was used to produce the summary. Gemini and SGE are not just "stochastic next-word selectors". That is only a fraction of what they do. When you do a search, SGE receives the top search results and uses the LLM to summarize content and then structure it as a nice, human-readable summary. Again, you could argue about how the citations are presented, but you cannot say that what it doing is not a citation.

Yep, they're integrating their search results. And that part does have citations. Of course those bits have been available for some time by just going a Google search. Maybe there's some use for AI to do selection on Google search results - I wonder how it picks? But regardless, LLM produced text currently cannot tell us what external source lead it to produce the sentence it produced, and anything that might make people believe that "LLMs produce citations" is deceptive.

@JonathanZ Again, you are incorrect. Gemini links generated statements - often one or a few sentences - to specific sources that support the ideas summarized in the sentence(s). SGE does something similar. How it picks is irrelevant. Why did I read and cite Bob's book on the topic instead of reading and citing Alice's book on the same subject? It doesn't matter. And I'm not claiming the LLMs produce citations - they don't and can't without additional stuff around them. Gemini and SGE can and do produce valid citations for content because they have more stuff than just the underlying LLM.

I, too, believe this is where the OpenAI partnership will lead; even just in a practical sense, I think there has to be a some practical benefit for OpenAI to partner with Stack, and it seems reasonable that the benefit is going to be more than access to Stack's content (which is widely believed to already have been scraped) for training. I'd wager, given that it's being advertised on the OverflowAPI page, that the partnership is more about novel access to purpose-built API/ infra to support something akin to these attributed summaries.

The pushback on this is also interesting to me; I've been using the Search Experiments AI tool for a bit now, and I have yet to find an attributed response that doesn't reasonably summarize the cited source... personally, I just haven't seen any reason to doubt the "citations" (whether in the proper sense or not is besides the point) provided, because they've always matched up with the source when I click through. Now, sometimes that source is just bad or contains wrong info, but that's not an AI summary problem. It doesn't seem to be generating that data, it seems to be summarizing.

@zcoop98 Exactly! We can debate what format the citations should be in and whether their presentation is appropriate. We can also debate Google's responsibility to ensure correct and validated content is returned via search results. But it is undisputable that citations exist, that citations are linked to generated content, and (so far, in my experience) that the summarized content and provided citations match up regardless of the correctness of the content being summarized.

I'm curious if the answer has changed for OpenAI's products. (I think your answer was written about ChatGPT's GPT-3 model.) Other models can search the internet, and the SO Blog shows that some models do attribute SE content, at least some of the time.

@Laurel As far as I can tell (using the free OpenAI products), it hasn't changed much. I see the picture in the SO blog post, but I posed the same question to ChatGPT as I did to Gemini (Why only one return statement?) and wasn't presented with any attempt for citation or attribution in three attempts. I don't have access to the SearchGPT prototype, so I can't make any claims about it. It seems like it should be unnecessary to include citation or attribution requests in the prompt.

Thomas, I think some of the confusion stems from: i) it isn't at all obvious that the citations are actually citing sources and are not tacked on after the fact. You explain this (that Gemini and SGE actually do keep track of their sources) in a comment, but you don't say that in your answer. I also assumed that the "citations" are created via web search post facto, so the thing could "cite" a post created long after it was trained, for instance, if it were available in search results. It would help if you explained in the answer [cont...]

[...cont]  ii) You mention the distinction between citation and attribution, but don't actually explain it in the answer. I actually came here from another comment of yours, and I expected to find an explanation of the differences, but I read your answer a couple of times and only found my explanation hidden in the comments.

@terdon Please check my edit. I added additional clarity. I think this addresses most of your points about the answer not including all of the information.

Just a heads up, I just did a touch of (liberal) copy editing to help harmonize the sections you added with what you already had, so that it sounded less like the original paragraph on "medium, means, and context" contradicted the references to citations vs. attribution section above it. I don't feel like I added anything nuts, but please roll back/ edit/ rework anything that doesn't feel right; I don't at all intend to put words in your mouth.
